# Running clock in excel workbook stops when other modules run in the VBA project

Tags: excel, vba

I have a running  clock on my excel workbook and whenever i run other codes in the workbook,the clock tends to stop . I have to always start the clock back whenever this happens. Is there anyways for the clock to auto run instead of me having to realise it and click it?

Comment: Is `clockOn` set to `False` anywhere else in the code (other running subs)?

Comment: So you stop the clock by calling stopclock()? If that's the case why is `clockOn` Global?

Comment: @paulbica - Because in the next iteration `runClock` will not schedule another occurrence of itself to occur thus halting the continuous loop.

Comment: @Niva - Do any of your 'other codes' use `On Error Resume Next`? This will halt the Application.OnTime's indefinite wait.

Comment: @Jeeped: `clockOn` doesn't need to be visible to all modules for this logic; it can be a private member of the module (global at module level only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
Option Explicit

Private clockStart As Boolean

Sub runClock(ByVal flag As Boolean)
    Dim functionWithParam As String
    Range("A1").Value = Now():  DoEvents
    functionWithParam = "'runClock " & Chr(34) & flag & Chr(34) & "'"
    If clockStart Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), functionWithParam
End Sub

Sub startClock()
    clockStart = True
    runClock True
End Sub

Sub stopClock()
    clockStart = False
End Sub
```

or this version:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then   '64 Bit Systems
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else           '32 Bit Systems
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long)
#End If

Private clockStart As Boolean

Sub runClock()
    While clockStart
        Range("A1").Value = Now()
        Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

Sub startClock()
    clockStart = True
    runClock
End Sub

Sub stopClock()
    clockStart = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you require the call to `runClock` in `stopClock`?

Comment: Okay I will try it! Nope i dont need to call it.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry but what does this part of the code means ?  functionWithParam = "'runClock" & Chr(34) & flag & Chr(34) & "'"
    If clockStart Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), functionWithParam

Comment: I removed the call `runClock` in `stopClock()` as tested by @Niva. The `functionWithParam` is a way to execute a function with parameters from `OnTime`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to use the default indefinite wait when the [Application.OnTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx)'s optional *LatestTime* parameter is left blank, why not consolidate several Application events that you likely use in your 'other codes' anyways?

```
Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    If bTGGL Then
        startClock
    Else
        stopClock
    End If
End Sub
```

At the beginning of your 'other codes', use `appTGGL bTGGL:=False` and at the end of your other sub procedures more simply as `appTGGL`.

The clock will be halted during operation. It sounds like `On Error Resume Next` to get over a `.Find` or something was going to break it anyways. As long as your procedure finishes, the clock will be restarted. If the other procedure(s) doesn't finish you've got bigger problems than a clock that is only right twice a day.

Remember to get rid of all the superfluous code in your other procedures like,

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Comment: Thanks ill try this as well:-)